# Did VS Have done

Tags: grammar

What is difference between the following statements:

> 1. Did you tell your parents  yet?
> 2. Have you told your parents yet?
> 3. Haven't you told your parents yet?

Are these questions correct? why do we use one over another in some cases? What is the difference in meaning?

Comment: Any decent English grammar book can answer all three of your questions. That's what grammar books are for. Here on ELL, people only answer specific questions you might have that cannot be answered by consulting a grammar book or a dictionary.

Comment: To my British ears, 1) is American, and I would never say it. Only 2 and 3 in British English.

Comment: The temporal adverb 'yet' makes the *present perfect* work much better than *past tense*.  The question with 'not' can't be unambiguously answered by a simple 'yes' or 'no'.

Comment: @ColinFine  to quote Henry Higgins, *"There even are places where English completely disappears / Well in America, they haven't used it for years! "*   :)

Comment: 1) is not American per se. Don't for one minute think that uneducated BrE speakers don't use that. It's just that the US has millions of speakers, so the likelihood of hearing it *via the media* may be greater.

Comment: @Lambie - not so sure about that. I'm British, and No1 to me sounds distinctly odd because of the addition of "yet" at the end.  "Did you tell your parents?" is absolutely fine.  Use of "yet" here just doesn't work with the simple past in this context, and I assume this is probably also true of American English, not just a British thing. I think if a student used this they could potentially lose marks in a test/exam.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes, the yet shouldn't be there. In any English, for a standard thing.

Comment: Yes, at best it's non-standard, colloquial, possibly regional (N.America).  I remember once visiting a supermarket in Australia, and after ringing up my purchase on the till the cashier asked me "Did you want a bag?".  I replied "No, I still want one". She looked perplexed.

Comment: @BillyKerr There are these **claims** re BrE but I'm afraid it's about standard English. Not just BrE.

Comment: @Lambie Absolutely. Do you think we could safely say that in example No.1, the use of "yet" would not be grammatical in any standard variety of English?  I'm not really one for making prescriptive pronouncements on grammar, but from the point of view of a student learning "standard" English grammar, it's quite important.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes, right. But I do not think this is a BrE.AmE thing. It just may **seem** that way given the difference in the number of speakers of both.

Comment: @Lambie It's interesting what Google ngram stats seem to say about it. In fact the difference is rather stark: [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Have+you+told+%2A+yet%2CDid+you+tell+%2A+yet&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) has zero hits for Did you tell * yet, versus [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Have+you+told+%2A+yet%2CDid+you+tell+%2A+yet&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) which shows it's a recent trend, since the 1980s. Of course this doesn't mean it's standard in Am.E

Comment: @BillyKerr ngrams is not for spoken English in particular. It is for more for written English...

Comment: @Lambie yeah I know. I'm taking the results with a pinch of salt.

Answer (score 1):

Both "Did you tell your parents yet?" and "Have you told your parents yet?" mean the same thing: you're just asking for information. As Colin mentioned in his comment, there may be cultural differences there. For me (in Canada), both sound equally common, but that may not be so in British English.

"Haven't you told your parents yet?" asks for the same information, but also expresses that you think the person should have done so already.